# Xcode 7 - Launch Screen localization doesn't work

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, xcode7

I've created a **splash screen** in **Swift** using **Xcode 7**. I've generated localizations as in the photo for different languages, but it doesn't work:

[image]

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fix it after i create InfoPlist.strings and create splash screen for each language and add below in each file

"UILaunchStoryboardName" = "LaunchScreen";
"UILaunchStoryboardName" = "LaunchScreenSP";

Comment: Could you please share the steps how you solved this issue. I have the same problem and couldn't figure out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Add two Launch Screen storyboards
2. You can find your info.plist added a key named "UILaunchStoryboardName"
3. Add an infoPlist.string file
4. Change the UILaunchStoryboardName = "ENLaunchScreen"; in your infoPlist.string to the name of storyboard you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, you can set some basic image at the launch screen, then create a view in app delegate and add in to window's subviews, also bring to front pretend that this is Launch screen.
now you can configure this view by code.
last use DispatchQueue asyncAfter to remove this view.